# streaming audio file is playing after getting pop to the View controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios7

I'm using AVPlayer to stream an audio file for my project. The problem I'm facing is the audio file plays after getting pop from the AudioPlayerVC.
Everything is okay when the audio plays on the AudioPlayerVC. It stops, plays and pauses too on AudioPlayerVC. But on the buffering time when I return back, it  plays after some sec. I can listen to sound but cannot stop or do anything else.

```
- (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender { 
    if (_audioToPlay.playing == YES) {
        [_audioToPlay stop];
    } else if (_audioToPlay.playing == NO || _audioToPlay.volume == 1.0 ) {
        _audioToPlay.volume = 0.0;
        [_audioToPlay stop]; 
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: can u post some code for reference.

Comment: - (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender {
   
         if (_audioToPlay.playing == YES)
         {
             [_audioToPlay stop];
         }
         else if (_audioToPlay.playing == NO || _audioToPlay.volume == 1.0 )
         {
             
             _audioToPlay.volume = 0.0;
             [_audioToPlay stop];
         }
          
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     
}

Comment: if you have defined your audio player as a property remove it and define it as simple object and then try your above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If below is not working then Refer [avplayer-continues-to-play-after-viewcontroller-is-removed-from-navigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073098/avplayer-continues-to-play-after-viewcontroller-is-removed-from-navigationcontro)

You can do is firstly `pause player` :

```
[yourAVPlayer pause];
```

Then `pop` to `Parent View Controller`

```
[self.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm doing it as -  [myAVPlayer stop];                                                             Then pop to Parent View Controller

[self.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];                                         is it a wrong way I'm using